# What are the costs involved with getting a 2 seat ultralight?

Tags: usa, ultralight

About 7 years ago I got my private pilots cert but I let my medical cert lapse.

Now that life is more settled I'd like to get back into flying but I want something that I can keep at home. I was thinking of a two seat ultralight with folding wings.

My questions are:

- What do I need to do to get back into the flight seat
- What are some good options for a 2 seat folding wing ultralight that has a few hour range
- What are some hidden costs of owning a new or used ultralight

Comment: If they ever ramp up production, I'd love to own an [Icon A5](https://www.iconaircraft.com/home) which is available with a trailer option.

Comment: In what country? The United States? I thought that 2-seat aircraft could not be considered ultralights in the US.

Comment: @TannerSwett The United States. I think there's specific guidelines for ultralights to fall into the FAA reg you're referring too. I have my private pilots cert though so I don't care, it doesn't affect me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What do I need to do to get back into the flight seat

Legally, not much. With the [recent third class medical reform you dont even need to get a medical.](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2017/january/10/faa-releases-final-rule-for-third-class-medical-reform) You will need to get a bi-annual flight review to get current as well as your takeoff/landing requirements for passenger carrying [as per FAR 61.57](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.57). While your bi-annual only needs to be an hour of ground and an hour of flight, if its been 7 years it will be well worth your time (and possibly an insurance requirement) to spend some more time on both.

> What are some good options for a 2 seat folding wing ultralight that
>   has a few hour range

Dont know much in this space so I wont comment

> What are some hidden costs of owning a new or used ultralight

There is one guy on the field I fly out of who has one of the [moving wing, snowmobile looking ultra lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Creation_Tanarg). He keeps it in the back of another guys hanger and takes the wing off every time he stores it. With that in mind last time I spoke to him he said it takes some time to get the wing on and off and he needs to plan for that when he flys. If I remember correctly he bought his new or close to new and it was in the space of 75K which frankly is quite a bit considering you can get a really nice airplane for way less than that. The wing is fabric/composite so outside storage is a no go. You can hop around on nice days with it but its VFR only which depending on your goals can be a limiting factor.

Comment: VFR is fine for me. I just want something I can take my girl around the state in and out to some Islands on. I just don't want to spend $1,000 a flight to do it with Cessna rentals :-)

Comment: Depends on distance, for the price a used VFR only Cherokee 140 may actually cost you less in the end of the day and you can store it outside on the field. I would explore the cost of a Cessna 150/152 as well both have performance marginally better than an ultralight and are way more plentiful in the used market.

Comment: Do the wings come off of those easily? My property isn't big enough to store an unfolded 150 unfortunately. I really don't want to pay hanger fees either. My goal is to get back into the sport but be thrifty this time. I jumped into my cert without thinking about costs and it scared me out.

Comment: They do not, but a tie down at most fields is pretty cheap if you are willing to store outside. Are you planning to fly on and off your property as well or just store and trailer?

Comment: My vision was to get something that I could store on a trailer and back into the driveway. Then when I want to fly, drive it 20 min to the local airport and go.

Comment: Fair enough, A decent enclosed trailer may cost you the same as 3-5 years of a cheap tie down rental. But anyway I would look at wingspans and what kind of hauling you would need to make it a reality. Im sure there are different kinds but the one I have seen has a single piece wing that is quite large.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59659/discussion-between-dave-and-anthony-russell).

Comment: Careful though, 3rd class medical reform does not automatically mean you don't need a medical, especially if you've had a medical revoked or surrendered. This is one of those instances where he will probably need to talk with an AME.

Comment: He states he let it lapse, I did assume that meant he simply let it expire and it was not revoked or surrendered.

Comment: @Dave I did read it wrong (thought he said due to medical reasons), but if that were the case and he has a medical condition that would otherwise require a waiver, he would still need to go through that process.